# assigning values to vectors of vectors

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, 2d

i have created a vector of vectors or 2d arrays of size n x n . i want to assign some n-2 values to each  position  to this vector, i.e for example grid[1][2]=3 and the values 3 should not be same for other position in a vector only grid[1][2] should have the value 3.
 could anybody help me with the code, also can we use srand function to do this?
                   Thanks

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Do you want to assign `n-2` values to *each* element in your 2D array?

Comment: `srand()` is only used if you have a random number, and isn't actually used to assign the number (`rand()` is used for that), just to seed the random number generator.

Comment: Are you wanting to fill the array with a random permutation of all the numbers from 1 to n*n, so each number from 1 to n*n is used exactly once?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you don't have any limitation on the random number generated, here is an example that populates and then print 2D vector array:

```
int n = 3;
std::vector<int> usedNumbers(n*n);
std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec(n);
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    vec[i].resize(n);
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        int randNum;
        while (std::find(usedNumbers.begin(), usedNumbers.end(), randNum = rand()) != usedNumbers.end()){}
        usedNumbers.push_back(randNum);
        vec[i][j] = randNum;
    }
}
// print the 2 dimentional vector
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    std::cout << "i:" << i << " j:" << j << " vec: " << vec[i][j] << std::endl;
```

This reference code also assumes that the random number should be unique in the entire 2D array.

you can play with the rand() function to reflect the maximum number you want (for example, random number x should be in the range of 0 < x < n), but a better option would be to use [random](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/).

Comment: If my answer helped you, please help me by accepting it (clicking the empty check mark). thanks :)